# using JSON with 'Hello World' as an example

Tags: android, web-services, json, httpwebrequest

I've not used JSON before and as Android doesn't support SOAP I'm trying to see how it differs. I can see the difference in parsing the response but I'm not clear how you send the request. Using a simple example like 'Hello World' can someone send me some code to give me an idea how you would send the request along with the Url. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON isn't a remote call API like Soap. It's just a data container format. It's protocol and API agnositic. You would need some sort of server-side script to actually generate the JSON, in Java, PHP, or whatever.

Comment: So would I be correct in assuming then that our existing .Net webservice would be of no use and that I would have to code a new .Net module that would receive a querystring from the Android app with the data to be processed and then send the resulting data back in a JSON style packet that would be parsed when received by the Android app.

Comment: I wouldn't say you'd need to scrap what you've got. Just change the bit the creates the xml content and replace it with a call to whatever the .NET JSON package is. I'm not a .net guy so I can't offer more specific guidance.

Comment: That's fine, what you have told me is very helpful. I'll scrap the SOAP WSDL and write a new .Net module which looks for a querystring instead.

Answer (score 1):

For an example of using JSON in Java / Android, please see http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/